# My Validation rule not throwing error

Tags: validation-rule

I want my VR to work when the field `Department Mob'hy` is not selected on two different record types. My VR shows no syntax error but still don't work.

```
OR (

AND ( ISBLANK( Departement_Mob_hy_Opp__c),
RecordType.Id = "01209000000EjLmAAK"),

AND (ISBLANK( Departement_Mob_hy_Opp__c),
RecordType.Id = "01209000000EjLSAA0")
)
```

Comment: are the Ids corrected? Do not use IDs, use DeveloperName. Ids could change when you deploy.

Comment: Try the 15-character long IDs instead of 18-character long ones. Even if that works, still think of a formula that does not use hard coded IDs.

Answer (score 7):

You're using the *18-digit* Id, while validation rules don't support that (see [this idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DrUyAAK)). It will support *15-digit* Id, but as mentioned in the comment, **avoid hard-coding your record type Id**.

You can rely on `DeveloperName` of the record type. It's similar to the API name of a custom field, is unique, and gives you some benefits over the Id:

- It will stay the same as you deploy through sandboxes and into production
- Allows admins/users to easily change the label to meet business
  changes while not changing the API name and breaking this VR.
- Is easier to understand what the VR is doing rather than seeing an Id which you do not know what it refers to.

You also don't need to repeat your `ISBLANK` and can move your `OR()` to simply contain either record type: this allows you to easily just add more record types as need be in the future.

```
AND(
    ISBLANK(Departement_Mob_hy_Opp__c),
    OR(
        RecordType.DeveloperName = "YourRecordTypeDeveloperName"),
        RecordType.DeveloperName = "YourRecordTypeDeveloperName2")
    )

)
```